# Extending existing cell libraries

Tags: yosys

I'm trying to create my own cell library in order to customize the mapping process. Does anyone have any idea on how to include a new cell library in the tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example project that maps to a library in liberty (.lib) format:

https://github.com/cliffordwolf/yosys/tree/master/examples/cmos

Cell library: `cmos_cells.lib`
Synthesis script: `counter.ys`

Comment: How do I learn the exact syntax and semantics of the .lib files used here? Also, do I need to provide the .lib file with a matching Verilog design that implements each of the cells mentioned in the .lib file? Please provide me with any references that might help me better understand how this works.

Comment: @AbdelAziz Just google for "Liberty File Format" for more information. No you don't neet to provide verilog models of your cells, liberty files contain all the information required.